# Are there any examples of rendering maps using GlympeMapView in Android?

Tags: glympse

Every project of seen in the SDKs examples folder is using a GlympseMapFragment.  I do not need something so heavyweight for my purposes.  I want to embed a GlympseMapViewGoogle in my app.  How do I go about doing this?  Are there any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the GlympseMapViewGoogle is not an object that can be used by itself to show a Glympse on a map. If you want to avoid using GlympseMapFragment you'll need to write your own code to deal with displaying users and tickets on a Google map.